# Are two events compatible/incompatible based only on their probability to happen?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have two events $A$ and $B$. We know that $\ P(A) = \frac{1}{3}$
and $P(\overline{B}) = \frac{1}{4}$ (meaning $P(B) = \frac{3}{4}$). How can I find out if $A$ and $B$ are compatible or not, using only their probability to happen?

Comment: What do you mean by compatible?

Comment: They are compatible if they can happen at the same time.

Comment: I guess they must be compatible if $P(A)\ge\frac 12$ and $P(B) \ge \frac 12$ (or $P(\overline{B}) < \frac 12$).

Comment: Sorry,$\ P(A) = \frac{1}{3}$, not $\frac{1}{2}$. Can you explain why is it like that, please?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $A,B$ are two non-compatible events, so they don't happen at the same time, i.e. they are disjoint. Of course $A\cup B \subset \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the whole event space.

Disjointness of $A$ and $B$ (for the "=") and the properties of the probability measure $P$ deliver: $$P(\Omega) \geq P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{3}{4} > 1,$$ yielding a contradiction since it has to hold $P(\Omega)=1$.